# Can you "hijack" rendering part of a Ractive template?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a "SuperSelect" control currently implemented as a Ractive component, which augments a regular drop-down select list with searching, filtering, extended option descriptions, and various other goodies. This generally works really well, except that I now need to fill one of these SuperSelects with approximately 7,800 options, and it gets *really* slow, and slows down the rest of the page as well. The problem seems to be Ractive's internal memory usage; if I re-implement the SuperSelect in vanilla JS, most of the problem goes away. Unfortunately, I can't see a good way to actually make use of my more-efficient SuperSelect without tearing out Ractive completely every place that it's used, which seems like throwing the baby out with the bathwater.

So, basically, I need a way to insert a chunk of DOM that's managed by other code into the middle of a Ractive template, while still allowing the controlling code to be notified when relevant keypaths are updated by the containing Ractive instance, and as far as I can tell none of the existing plugin/extension methods quite fit the bill. So far, I've come up with two hacks combining multiple plugin methods that might work:

1. Combine an adapter and a decorator. In this case, the decorator would simply replace whatever element it was attached to with the DOM fragment for the SuperSelect. A special SuperSelect control object would then be added to the Ractive instance's data with an adaptor that would let it participate in 2-way binding with the rest of the template, and independently communicate with the decorator code to update the SuperSelect DOM.
2. Combine a decorator with a mini-component and `ractive.observe`. In this case, the decorator would again replace a particular template element with the SuperSelect DOM fragment, but it would only be used locally within a component whose template consists of nothing but that one decorated element. The component would serve as a means of resetting the keypath root, so that the decorator code can `observe` a static set of keypaths in order to update the state of the SuperSelect DOM regardless of how the SuperSelect is embedded in a larger parent ractive instance.

Is there any simpler way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes – you could create a component with an empty DOM node and re-render its contents inside an observe handler:

```
const SuperSelect = Ractive.extend({
  template: `
    <div><!-- we'll render this bit ourselves --></div>`,
  onrender () {
    const div = this.find( 'div' );
    this.observe( 'items', items => {
      // render the items however we want
    });
  }
});
```

More complete demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9w9rrr9s/